# Plotting map with coordinate from a csv file using Python turtle

Tags: python, csv, turtle-graphics

Ι am trying to plot a map from a csv file using turtle graphic.

My csv file is here: http://textuploader.com/5nau2

My program:

```
import turtle
import csv
import math

def drawMap():
    filename = "C:\python-exercises\coordinates1.csv"

    trace = turtle.Turtle()
    trace.up()

    #scr = Screen()

    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        reader = reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:

            x = (row[0])
            y = (row[1])
            trace.goto(x,y)
            trace.write(".")
    raw_input()
    #scr.mainloop()
drawMap()
```

But it is not displaying anything, and also generates errors like:

```
x = row([0])

keyError: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should get you started. The file you are trying to read in is not in `csv` format, so instead of using the csv library you could read the rows in yourself as follows:

```
import turtle
import math

def drawMap():
    filename = r"C:\python-exercises\coordinates1.csv"

    trace = turtle.Turtle()
    trace.up()

    #scr = Screen()

    with open(filename, 'r') as f_input:
        for row in f_input:
            row = row.strip('()\n').split(',')
            x = float(row[0])
            y = float(row[1])
            trace.goto(x,y)
            trace.write(".")
    raw_input()
    #scr.mainloop()
drawMap()
```

This takes each row, removes the outer parenthesis and newline and splits it into two columns. The columns are then converted to `floats` for your turtle program to interpret.

If you are ever not sure about why something is not working, add some `print` statements to see what is happening.

Also, do not forget to prefix your filename path with `r`, this stops Python from trying to interpret the backslashes in your string.